# When mounting named volumes, under what conditions is data copied from the container?

Tags: docker

I know that, in some cases, mounting a named volume on a container can cause data from the container to be automatically copied to the volume, similar to what happens with anonymous volumes.

However, even after reading the docs, it's unclear to me what are the exact conditions that trigger the copy.

I created a `test` image with two files `/root/a/a.txt` and `/root/b/b.txt` and performed the following experiment:

```
$ docker volume create --name hello
hello
$ docker run -v hello:/root/a test /bin/true
$ docker run -v hello:/root/b test /bin/true
$ docker run -ti -v hello:/tmp/result test /bin/bash
```

(now inside the container)

```
# cd /tmp/result
# ls
a.txt
```

It seems that the data is copied into the volume after the first mount, and not afterwards (despite not having specified `nocopy` for the second mount).

Do named volumes have hidden state that tracks if they haven't been mounted yet? Or is the copy triggered just by the volume being empty? If copying only happens the first time, what is the purpose of the `nocopy` modifier to the `-v` option of `docker run`?

I'm using Docker version 1.11.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my testing, it appears to trigger the copy when the volume is empty when you run the container.

I tested with a volume that was populated from a first mount point in one container. Using this named volume on a second mount point of another container showed the contents of the first mount point. I then deleted the contents but the container was still running and volume still mounted. Finally, I started a second container with a different mount point and the contents from the second mount point were then populated.